# Difference Between Imrei Emes and Toras Emes

Tags: jewish-books, chasidut-hasidism

I noticed that Imrei Emes and Toras Emes, works written by R' Leibele Eiger, are often printed together. What's the difference between these two works? Did he simply compose two different commentaries on Chumash and Moadim?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got my hands on a cop of each. Toras Emes was penned by R' Leibele Eiger himself, while Imrei Emes are teachings recorded by his talmidim.